# Lemma about complete subgraphs of r-parite graphs by Bollobás

Tags: graph-theory

***Lemma connected with counting z(m,n;s,t)***: Let $m, \, n,\, s, \, t, \, r, \, k$ be integers, $0 \leqslant s \leqslant m$, $0\leqslant t \leqslant n$,\ $0\leqslant k$, $ 0\leqslant r \leqslant m$ and let $G=G_2(m,\, n)$ be a graph of size $z=my=km+r$ without$K(s, \, t)$. Then
\begin{equation}
m\binom{y}{t} \leqslant (m-r) \binom{k}{t}+r\binom{k+1}{t}\leqslant (s-1)\binom{n}{t}.
\end{equation}

Why is this lemma so important? Why this "trivial Lemma allows us to recognize certain extremal graphs without actually examining any other graphs"?

Comment: Upper bound for what? If you do not provide more context, this question will probably be closed.

Comment: What made you think it is so important? Please give references!

Comment: Is this a lemma from this article? http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(75)90011-4 Unfortunately it seems the PDF version I can access is missing the last 5 pages of the article.

Comment: It is from book "Extremal graph theory" by Bollobas, quote:
"trivial Lemma allows us to recognize certain extremal graphs without actually examining any other graphs"
comes from the same book either.